# "Failed to fetch liborbit2_2.14.19-0.2_amd64.deb" when installing Java

Tags: apt, software-installation

When I try to install `openjdk-7-jdk`, I get the following message:

```
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/orbit2/liborbit2_2.14.19-0.2_amd64.deb  
Size mismatch
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Try executing the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

From `man apt-get`:

> clean
>
> Clears out the local repository of retrieved package files. It removes everything but the lock file from `/var/cache/apt/archives/` and `/var/cache/apt/archives/partial/`.

So this will delete all local repository and retrieved packaging files using `apt-get clean` (forcing `apt-get update` to re-download everything), then re-downloading them using `apt-get update` (this will hopefully fix the size mismatch) and then installing `openjdk-7-jdk` using `apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`.